# Why is Geopy Distance.Distance wrong?

Tags: python, geopy

From GeoDjango Point Field, I get the following points:

```
object1.point = "POINT(-113.4741271000000040 53.4235217000000020)"
object2.point = "POINT(-113.5013688000000229 53.5343457999999970)"
```

Then I calculate the distance using `geopy`:

```
from geopy import distance
from geopy import Point

p1 = Point("-113.4741271000000040 53.4235217000000020")
p2 = Point("-113.5013688000000229 53.5343457999999970")
result = distance.distance(p1,p2).kilometers
print result
# 5.791490830933827
```

But using this tool: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
I get a distance of 12.45km

Why is there such a big discrepancy?

Comment: I get 5.77 km with the tool you linked. Could you try it again?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got lat/long the wrong way round. Try:

```
p1 = Point("53.4235217000000020 -113.4741271000000040")
p2 = Point("53.5343457999999970 -113.5013688000000229")
```

Gives me result = 12.466096663282977

Comment: I made an assumption that you're measuring in Edmonton rather than somewhere in Antarctica :)

Comment: You are right, Edmonton is right. Lat = 53, lon = -113. But, when representing a point in Geodjango PointField, it's done as "POINT({lon} {lat})". With geopy, is it Point("{lat} {lon}")? (See correction). If this is the case, how would I find the distance between two GeoDjango point fields?

Comment: Not sure - not familiar with GeoDjango classes. You might want to post a django question. :) Have you tried the obvious conversion via strings? Also I'm suspicious of any framework that use lon/lat instead of the very conventional lat/log. :)

Comment: FWIW, using the `Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse()` method of ([the Python module](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/other.html#python) from C. F. F. Karney's [GeographicLib](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/) I get 12466.096663762537 metres.

Comment: For documentation sake: geopy has a [`lonlat()`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.distance.lonlat) method to convert a `(lon, lat)` tuple to a `(lat, lon)` tuple. If you have a Django `Point` instance, you can use the `.tuple` attribute so you can do: `lonlat(*my_pnt.tuple)`. Btw: the order of lat/lon is unfortunately not standardized and differs widely in systems, so it's not a case of geopy/Django being wrong or right.